# GCE instance - Unable to grow disk?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, partition

I have a GCE VM instance with a 9000GB disk:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 19.5T  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  8.8T  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    3M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0  124M  0 part /boot/efi
```

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  372K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       8.7T  8.3T  105M 100% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I just followed the steps here (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) to try to increase the disk size. I've edited the disk to 20000GB.

However, I can't seem to grow the partition table on the machine to take advantage of the increased size.

When I try to run the commands in the guide, I get:

```
$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 1
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by -14579398752 [fudge=2048]
```

Does that mean it didn't work?

resize2fs doesn't work either:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
The filesystem is already 2359262988 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to follow the same documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) and found no issues:

1. create VM instance:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create disk-resize --zone=us-central1-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200414 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --boot-disk-size=9000GB --boot-disk-device-name=disk-resize

   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/instances/disk-resize].
   WARNING: Some requests generated warnings:
   - Disk size: '9000 GB' is larger than image size: '10 GB'. You might need 
   to resize the root repartition manually if the operating system does not 
   support automatic resizing. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd for details.

   NAME         ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
   disk-resize  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               YY.128.15.YY  XX.222.86.XX  RUNNING
   ```
2. check disk space before any changes:

   ```
   disk-resize:~$ df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
   tmpfs           369M  884K  369M   1% /run
   /dev/sda1       8.6T  1.3G  8.6T   1% /
   tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   /dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
   /dev/loop0       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
   /dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
   /dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/126
   tmpfs           369M     0  369M   0% /run/user/1001
   ```
3. increase disk size up to 20000GB:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute disks resize disk-resize --size 20000GB --zone us-central1-a

   ...
   Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/disks/disk-resize].
   ...
   sizeGb: '20000'
   ...
   status: READY
   ```

   ...
4. install `growpart`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt -y install cloud-guest-utils
   ```
5. grow the partition:

   ```
   disk-resize:~$ lsblk
   NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   loop0     7:0    0 93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
   loop1     7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
   loop2     7:2    0 97.1M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-sdk/126
   sda       8:0    0 19.5T  0 disk 
   ├─sda1    8:1    0  8.8T  0 part /
   ├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part 
   └─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
   ```

   and

   ```
   disk-resize:~$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 1
   CHANGED: partition=1 start=227328 old: size=18874140639 end=18874367967 new: size=41942812639,end=41943039967
   ```

   and

   ```
   disk-resize:~$ lsblk
   NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   loop0     7:0    0 93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
   loop1     7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
   loop2     7:2    0 97.1M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-sdk/126
   sda       8:0    0 19.5T  0 disk 
   ├─sda1    8:1    0 19.5T  0 part /
   ├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part 
   └─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
   ```
6. extend the file system (ext4) on the disk to use the added space:

   ```
   disk-resize:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
   resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
   Filesystem at /dev/sda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
   old_desc_blocks = 1125, new_desc_blocks = 2500
   The filesystem on /dev/sda1 is now 5242851579 (4k) blocks long.
   ```
7. check available disk space:

   ```
   disk-resize:~$ df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
   tmpfs           369M  884K  369M   1% /run
   /dev/sda1        19T  1.4G   19T   1% /
   tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   /dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
   /dev/loop0       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
   /dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
   /dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/126
   tmpfs           369M     0  369M   0% /run/user/1001
   ```

Let's compare:

- before:

  ```
  /dev/sda1       8.6T  1.3G  8.6T   1% /
  ```
- after:

  ```
  /dev/sda1        19T  1.4G   19T   1% /
  ```

**To solve your issue**:

- compare your steps to mine
- check if you have [required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#permissions-required-for-this-task_2)
- check if you resized disk of VM on step 3 via Console before step 5

  ```
  $ gcloud compute disks list
  NAME         LOCATION       LOCATION_SCOPE  SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
  disk-resize  us-central1-a  zone            20000    pd-standard  READY
  ```
- check current usage of disk quota at `IAM&Admin` -> `Quotas` -> set **`Quota type`** to `All quotas` -> set **`Service`** to `Compute engine API` -> set **`Metric`** to `Persistent disk standard (GB)` -> set **`Location`** to `NAME_OF_YOUR_ZONE`

If you still have an issue please update your question with your steps, commands and outputs

In addition, have a look at [this example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resize-your-persist-disk-on-google-cloud-on-the-fly-b3491277b718).